# Is there a better way to rebase on branch A from branch B?

Tags: git

At the moment I use the following script to get the latest `master` and put my changes on top of it:

```
current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
git checkout master && git pull && git checkout $current_branch && git rebase master
```

Is there a more concise way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly `pull --rebase` from remote master. Let's say the remote is called `origin` and your are in *current branch*, then this is all:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```